# Rails Architecture: Need to keep count of customers processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app which takes a customer object and pings an API. If that API returns a result, the customer object is saved. Otherwise, it's discarded.

My app only allows users to process 100 customers per month (regardless of the amount of customers saved or discarded)

What's the best way to accomplish this? Here's what I can think of:

1. An easy way would be to save *all* customer objects, and then just add an additional attribute to determine whether the API returned a result for this customer. I could make a SQL call to determine how many customers were processed in the last 30 days. This way kind of sucks because I'd have to save a ton of additional records (ratio is somewhere like 100 to 1).
2. I could add a customers_processed column to the User object. Each time a customer is processed, I could up the count in that column. This seems okay to me except I'm not sure how to implement the timing aspect using this approach. i.e I can easily see the total number of customers processed, but how can I see how many customers were processed in the last 30 days?

Comment: Does "per month" mean "October 1st - 31st" or does it mean "last 30 days" (ie. rolling)?

Comment: last 30 days (rolling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach depends on the exact requirements.  There is a difference between needing to know how many customers were processed by a particular user in the given month versus how many customers were processed by a particular user in the past 30 days.

If you are going with the past 30 days route, your solution will be more complex.  You'll need a separate table with three columns: `user_id`, `date`, and `customers_processed_count`.  The `user_id` and `date` would need to be a unique combination.  Having a count per day per user will allow you to determine the count for any 30-day window of time.

If instead you only care about how many customers have been processed per user in the given month, you don't need an extra table.  You can just have the `customers_processed` column like you suggested plus a date column `customers_processed_month`.  When you increment the `customers_processed` count by one, first check that `customers_processed_month` matches the current month.  If `customers_processed_month` is not the current month, reset the `customers_processed` count to zero and set `customers_processed_month` to the current month: `Date.current.beginning_of_month`.  Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-beginning_of_month

Comment: Is the first approach (rolling) much better than just saving all the customer records in the first place?

Comment: It depends on how many customers your users are processing and what the spread of days are.  The worst case as far as table size in your first approach would be N users multiplied by 100 customers per month.  If you are just storing counts of customers per day, the worst case would by N users multiplied by ~30 days per month.  So maybe a third of the size but you are correct in that they are comparable (order of N rows). If you ever increased your rate limits though the benefits are clear. I doubt the number of days per month will change in the near future :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an alternate answer that is a hybrid between Sean's two answers. Basically I wanted to keep a count of customers processed in a 30 day period (but not necessarily by month e.g. August, September because user's can sign up any time).

You'll need a separate table with three columns: `user_id, date, and customers_processed_count`.

```
def increase_customers_processed_count
    date = Date.today
    record = self.user.customer_records.where('date > ?',  30.days.ago).first_or_create(date: date)
    record.increase_count
end
```

This way, a new record is only being created if we're out of 30 day range. Hope this helps someone.